# Autofit label, CGSize gives value zero

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uilabel

I want to change the size of a label depending on how big it is.  I set a breakpoint on the first line, and as I go down I see that "tagsSize" actually has a value when I get to the line that starts with CGSize, it is then changed to zero after that line.  I actually used this same code, with changes of course, in a different class of the same project and it is working fine.  I am probably looking over something.  Please take a look and let me know what I am doing wrong.

```
_tagsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Astronaut", @"iPhone", @"iOS", @"Software Engineer", @"Carpentry", @"Landscape Design", @"Doctor", @"Actor", @"CEO", @"iOS Developer", @"Software Engineer", @"Carpentry", @"Landscape Design", @"Doctor", @"Actor", @"CEO", @"iOS Developer", nil];
_tagsString = [_tagsArray componentsJoinedByString:@", "];

_tagsLbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:18];
CGSize tagsSize = [_tagsString sizeWithFont:[_tagsLbl font]];

NSLog(@"%f", tagsSize.width);
CGFloat tagsWidth = tagsSize.width;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you alloc the UILabel? I think it is nil when you use it..

Comment: That was my problem, I hadn't allocated it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
CGSize size = [string sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:fontb]
                        constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(TEXTLABEL_WIDTH, 1000) 
                               lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap];
```